# Make a new line in a GridView

Tags: gridview, asp.net-2.0, newline

I've an ASP.Net 2.0 Gridview control that I can bind a List<T> too, for a specific field in List<T> like "Old" and "New" I want to place new line characters that will break the text into separate lines e.g.:

```
Column1=Value1 Column2=Value2
```

to become:

```
Column1=Value1
Column2=Value2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are two ways to do this:

1. Change the way your List is formatted, using string concatenation to join the two columns into one field (something like: `column1 + '<br>' + column2`). If you're using SQL, for example, you can use a query with string concatenation ([more info](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html))
2. Use the gridview's events: `OnDataBound` and\or `OnRowDataBound` to change how data is viewed in the gridview control. ([more info](http://weblogs.asp.net/meligy/archive/2008/01/25/gridview-databinding-events.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the Gridview column to a templated column, and then do your special formatting there.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
   <ItemTemplate>
      Column 1 : <%# Eval("Column1") %> <br />
      Column 2 : <%# Eval("Column2") %>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```