# Show records on the newline in ASP.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have added all necessary columns to datatable which I've created and then

```
     For i=0 to num step 1
       str1 = str1 ds.Tables("document").rows(i).item("name").ToString & " , "
     Next

     str1 = str1.Substring(0, str1.Length - 1)
     dr = dt.NewRow()
     dt.Rows.Add(id, category, str1)
```

My final output in gridview is "**client, vendor**"

I want that to look like this ->

```
     client
     vendor
```

i.e I want to show records on the new line ..How to do that it in gridview?

Comment: you may want to have a look at - [Make a new line in a GridView][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383699/make-a-new-line-in-a-gridview

Comment: @Morten: As you've probably now realized; SE comments don't support all flavours of link markdown. Links need to be in `[this syntax](http://stackoverflow.com)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i=0 to num step 1

     str1 = str1 ds.Tables("document").rows(i).item("name").ToString & " , "

Next

str1 = str1.Substring(0, str1.Length - 1)

dr = dt.NewRow()

dt.Rows.Add(id, category, str1)
```